# Import macro variables from a separate .egp file?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a project that utilizes two separate EGP files for two different stages of data processing. In the first file, I calculate a specific number and store it in a macro variable. Is there a way to import that macro variable into the second file, similar to how you might import various objects with an .RDA file in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does an Enterprise Guide project file even store values of macro variables?

Write the value of the macro variable into a dataset

```
data '/some directory/that SAS server can see/my_mvars.sas7bdat';
   length mname $32 value $300 ;
   mname='MYMACRO';
   value=symget(mname);
   output;
run;
```

or a text file

```
data _null_ ;
   file '/some directory/that SAS server can see/my_mvars.sas';
   put '%let MYMACRO=' "&mname" ;
run;
```

when the first project runs.

Then read it back in the second project from the dataset:

```
data _null_;
   set '/some directory/that SAS server can see/my_mvars.sas7bdat';
   call symputx(mname,value);
run;
```

or the text file

```
%include '/some directory/that SAS server can see/my_mvars.sas' / source2;
```